# Creating java: JNDI namespace in Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty

It seems that Liberty uses the default JNDI namespace. I've been using it, and it works fine.

However, I have a utility JAR that I'd like to use (I cannot change it). This  external jar does a lookup for a JNDI name like this: 
`"java:comp/env/jdbc/MAINDB"`

Is there a way to declare this name in my application, so that I can use this JAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a resource ref lookup. Assuming you are in an EE Web or EJB context when you call that code you can simply define a resource-ref in the web.xml or ejb-jar.xml for the calling web or ejb module.